# Quod eam doctrinam mihi dederis docendam

Tags: latin-to-english-translation

How would I translate the bolded part of this sentence?

"Gloriam tibi tribuo sapientiae ac iustitiae, mi Pater, **quod eam doctrinam mihi dederis docendam,** quam ii soli rejiciunt, sive quae fructu caret tantummodo apud eos quos propria sua culpa & pertinacia indociles atque incruabiles facit, absque ulla ipsius doctrinae, tua, meave culpa."

Literally it seems to be: "I ascribe the glory of wisdom and righteousness to You, My Father, because you delivered to me that doctrine which has to be taught. . ."

Or, more fluidly: "I ascribe the glory of wisdom and righteousness to You, My Father, because you delivered to me that doctrine which I am to teach. . ."

Comment: That literal translation would be my interpretation too. Is there a reason to think it's less straightforward than that?