# Quicquid modified by a future passive participle

Tags: latin-to-english-translation

Having a little trouble with the phrase "**Quicquid dat Mihi Pater salvandum id** ad Me veniet, supple ex officio, vel venire debet."

What is the best way to translate the bolded part? In particular, how does "salvandum" modify "quicquid?"

Perhaps something like this: "Whatever the Father gives to Me which must/has/is to be saved will come to Me. . ."

I feel like I am missing something, however.

Answer (score 5):

This is the same construction as in [your other question](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/18964/quod-eam-doctrinam-mihi-dederis-docendam), *dare* with a future passive participle. In this construction the participle expresses the purpose for which something is given, so your literal translations are basically correct. But they could be made more idiomatic by simply saying "whatever the Father gives to Me to save", or in the other question, "because you gave me this doctrine to teach".

Cf. this example from [Lewis and Short](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=dare&la=la#lexicon): *Lycurgus agros locupletium plebi, ut servitio, colendos dedit*, i.e. "gave the fields to the plebs to cultivate".